# What is the best way to generate html code after receiving json data from an ajax request using a template library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing something like this, but its a bit pain to style. Is there any other way like using templates?

```
   <div id="resultpanel"></div>

    <script>
    function parseData(jsonresults){
        var results = JSON.parse(jsonresults);
        jQuery("#resultpanel").empty();

        for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
            var divph = document.createElement("div");
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var p = document.createElement("p");

            img.src=results[i].logoname;
            p.innerHTML=results[i].perigrafh;
            jQuery(divph).append(img);
            jQuery(divph).append(p);            
            jQuery("#resultpanel").append(divph);   

        }       
     }
    </script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [`underscore templates`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for something pretty straightforward, or something like [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.io/) or [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for something more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way.

```
var html = "<div><img src=" + results[i].logoname + "/><p>" + results[i].perigrafh + "</p></div>"; 
jQuery("#resultpanel").append(html);
```

This is just an alternative way of doing it.

Maybe you can also instead of returning a json object, rather generate the html on the server side, return it and append the result.

Comment: I am not sure I would like to generate html code in server side and send that from network. Also I am using json strictly in this application. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't Know You'll only Looking some template engine or below solution can also help you simplfy.

```
 var Main= jQuery("#resultpanel");
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
    var html="";
     html="<div><img src="+results[i].logoname+ "/><p>"+results[i].perigrafh+"</p></div>";
     Main.append(html);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you query the data in JSON-format it would be easier for you:
cf. $.getJSON() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
So it boils all down to

```
$.getJSON(sourceUrl, function(results){
    elems=result.map(function(o){return "<div><img src='"+o.src+"'></img><p>"+o.perigrafh+"</p></div"});
    $("#resultpanel").html(elems.join(""));
});
```